# WebRTC, browser doesn't ask for permission to use camera and microphone - but locally it does

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm testing the https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#8 and locally my browser asks for permission to use the camera and microphone - and things works.

When I upload the code to a server on a real domain, my browser doesn't ask for permissions and I get an error from getUserMedia() with permission denied.

How can I prevent this?

I'm testing in Google Chrome, but would like the fix to work across Chrome, Firefox and Opera (as they support WebRTC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using HTTPS do you?

Remember that the newsest cool toys are only available to sites that load from secure origins. Localhost is just an exception to this.

If you think implementing HTTPS is pain in the ass or it is expensive, then take a look to Cloudlflare, $0.00 for a reverse proxy with free Comodo HTTPS certificate.

Or try this free certification authority https://letsencrypt.org/

I spoke to the guy behind this project at a securoty conference in Paris a month ago, and he explained that only thing they don't support is wildcard certificates. This should not be a problem for you. Unless you wanna have HTTPS with your own domain in your Content Delivery Network.

About browser compatibility, check this thread:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/which-browsers-and-operating-systems-support-lets-encrypt/4394

Comment: Hmm, can one easily install https running on node.js with http/node-static and let's encrypt?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it "install" ... as the certificate is just a file needed for a cryptographic process that allows you to sign your messages. The main task is just to get the certificate valid for your domain. Then you can configure your node server to use the certificate. Thats all. But if you need help automating most of stuff, check this link:  https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-express

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTPS protocol then Chrome should remember your first choice. Click on site favicon in address bar to change current preferences.

Comment: It simply doesn't ask for permissions - not even at first. I've checked with settings for exceptions etc.